# WCF vs Sockets sending texts

Tags: c++, wcf, sockets, text, tcp

i'm trying to send a text file from a client (linux) to a server (windows) but i'd like to make that automatic, and i was searching ways to do that until i found WCF and socket programming...
i've already tested sending bytes using TCP protocol from a client to a server and it worked but i don't know how i send text files...

My question is, which is the easier way to do this and will give me the best results?

i'm not an expert at this so i'd appreciate if you have patience, thanks!

Comment: How big are the files you need to transfer, and what kind of security do you need about the transfer? Have you considered just using HTTP instead of raw sockets? HTTP clients are fairly common and simple to use, and you could easily write the windows side using ASP.NET MVC (WebApi) or WCF.

Comment: i need to send files with no more than 10 mb and i'm looking for the securest way to do this... It's possible to execute a c++ program sending files to a server (with a c++ program running too) through HTTP?